# Stored procedure in phpMyAdmin gives error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am trying to write a stored procedure in PHPmyAdmin, but it gives the following message: "Error". 
So it is not really clear to me what I am doing wrong.

I have the following stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Authenticate
(IN LUsername varchar(20),
 IN LPassword varchar(20),
 OUT Result bit)

 BEGIN

DECLARE DUsername VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE DPassword VARCHAR(20);

SET DUsername = (select username from members where username = @LUsername);
SET DPassword = (select `password` from members where username = @LUsername);

IF DUsername = @LUsername AND DPassword = @LPassword THEN
    SET @Result = 1;
ELSE
    SET @Result = 0;
END IF

    SELECT @Result;

 END // 
 DELIMITER ;
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the this procedure?

(I have the idea that something is going wrong with the "END // DELIMITER ;" part.)

Comment: not sure but maybe the ; after END IF?

Comment: Thank you, I feel really stupid now.. hehe